# 4L60E Reverse and 1st Only after Transgo HD2 Kit

Tags: chevrolet, transmission, 4l60e

I have a 1999 4L60E from a 1999 Suburban that has been rebuilt twice successfully, and then had a TransGo 4L60E-HD2 shift kit installed that ultimately led to where it's at now with it's reverse and 1st only issue. I've been through quite a bit of troubleshooting and am basically at a loss

- Speedometer is working correctly
- Both shift solenoids have a resistance of 25 Ohms and click nicely with a 9v battery
- If my transmission control/PCM is unplugged completely it limps still in
  1st gear (which to my understanding is supposed to be impossible, since both solenoids being off should be 3rd)
- You can kind of feel the transmission try to shift to 2nd *barely* when it's supposed to, and then stops "trying"
- Commanding gears with the trans controller doesn't change anything
- Using the gear selector/tree also doesn't get out of 1st/R
- Sonnax Corvette servo installed with just enough shims to allow the input shaft to still be hand-rotatable
- Nothing I've torn down so far has any wear, and there's been no odd noises coming from anywhere while driving
- TPS shows correctly in my transmission controller software, reading from about .5v to 3.4v

Based on what I can find out by other forums and such, this collection of symptoms seems to be a very uncommon one. It was working 100% before the shift kit install, which only had us replace parts in the valve body, but it was never able to shift out of first since.

I currently have the transmission out with the valve body partially disassembled. What should I be testing?

Comment: Send it to Precision Transmissions - they have some really good videos on youtube.

Comment: @SolarMike Lol I'd rather fix it, this is a project/not my daily driver and my goal is to learn how to fix issues like this

Comment: Check to see if they have done one for your tranny - may be they say the one thing that might help. Just think their comments as they take it apart are **so** good "oh look been slammin' it into drive - classic evidence" etc :)

Comment: They did not , but we solved it watching my personal favorite, Transmission Bench guy, answer posted!

Answer (score 0):

Found out what was wrong! It was my stupidity, unfortunately, but that's the goal I suppose, is to make mistakes and learn.

So the problem was, that while installing we broke off the top of the 3-2 downshift solenoid, and ended up needing to replace it. Somewhere in the middle of that, we left out the 3-2 control valve and spring completely. Luckily when tearing it down we noticed that as the issue, found the parts, reinstalled, and everything worked wonderfully!

[image]

The rest of the shift kit instructions were followed to the letter, including flipping all the valve body pistons upside and whatnot, and it's working great.